# Is dexguard preventing simple LVL cracks?

Tags: android, proguard, android-lvl

I just have learnt the hard way that standard android LVL + proguard does not guarantee any piracy protection against simple cracks using tools like antilvl. I am working to find a reasonable way to ensure that my android apps are not pirated. I have found commercial proguard alternative called dexguard. It's quite expensive (375 EUR for the cheapest license) but I would buy it if I knew that it will protect my apps against script kiddies and amateur app crackers. I don't have a problem if some really smart cracker beats my piracy protection, but if any script kiddie can do it then it's a showstopper.

1. Do you have any experience with dexguard protection of LVL code?
2. Will just replacing proguard with dexguard and leaving standard LVL
   checks be enought to deter script kiddies?
3. If dexguard is not a simple way of protecting my lvl code, what other way you suggest?

Comment: I used to use DexGuard but just recently they've increased their prices. They just quoted me 5000 EUR/yr when last year it was around 375 EUR/yr. While I had their protection I found it good, but the protection now costs more than my app makes and it's no longer feasible for me :(

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Developers may be reluctant to talk about their defense measures. My experience, as the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard:

1. Feedback from DexGuard users is very positive. It's a war out there, but processed applications are holding up well, even against dedicated hackers.
2. DexGuard comes with a series of samples, including one that shows how to harden the License Verification Library. It adds layers of protection against hacking and tampering.  Each processed application is different. This breaks one-click cracking tools, which look for patterns and apply simple modifications.
3. DexGuard is simple to use: you can apply your existing ProGuard configuration and then specify which parts of the application have to be toughened. You can still combine DexGuard with other measures, like native code or running part of the application on a server.